# HeapDump and Memory leak in Java

Tags: java, memory, hashmap, classloader, objectmapper

We have a Spring Boot application running in Open Shift where the pod memory was around 3 GB to 4 GB.

Recently a new process has been added to the Spring Boot project, and the memory usage is now around 8 GB and sometimes goes up to 13 GB.

I have downloaded a heapdump file using ../actuator/heapdump which executed the gc (manually) and it cleared out the garbage in the memory making it around 3 GB.

I opened the heapdump in VisualVM, and I noticed there are many dominators in descending order like classloader, hashmap, objectmapper, etc.

What's the proper way to write a hashmap in Java?? ... !!
How to configure gc to make it cater for all unused/unlinked objects?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iLeL.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What's new process was added? Maybe is it xlsx reader?

Comment: @Shakirov Ramil, the new process means some new rest API (inside it's using hashmaps and objectmappers) and some utilities methods.